# Show that there is a bijection between $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $d>1$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and $r_1, r_2$ are two positive integers(not necessarily distinct) in the set $\{1,2,\cdots,d-1\}$. For some positive integer $u$, let $S_1:=\{n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}: dn+r_1\leqslant u\}$ and $S_2:=\{m\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}: dm+r_2\leqslant u\}$. To examine that there is a bijection between $S_1$ and $S_2$.

So far I have not found any counter example and I belive the statement is true. But getting stuck to establish it. Had it been the sets of inetegrs of the form $dk+r$ then $f(dn+r_1)=dm+r_2$ would have been enough to finish but currently the sets are containing those positive integers that satisfy the above inequalities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true , for example take d=5 , r1=1 , r2=3 and u=2 . Then
S1={1} and S2={} . And no bijection between them

Comment: I agree with you. Indeed it was a typing  mistake from end. The sets collect the values natural numbers as well 0. In this way, your example supports the statement.